# do I need a lock?

Tags: java, concurrency

```
MyObject myObj ...

public void updateObj(){
     MyObject newObj = getNewMyObject();
     myObj = newObj;
}

public int getSomething(){
     //O(n^2) operation performed in getSomething method
     int something = myObj.getSomething();
     return something;
}
```

Suppose the main thread periodically calls `updateObj()` and a child thread calling `getSomething()` method pretty often.

Do I need a lock (or declare methods as synchronized) before `myObj = newObj;` and `int something = myObj.getSomething();`

Someone argued I don't need a lock here because in Java, assignment operations (e.g `myObj = newObj;`) is atomic. But what I don't get it is that `myObj.getSomething();` this is not an atomic operation but its O(n^2) so I think a locking is still needed. Is this correct?

Comment: `declare methods as synchronized` will not work.  As you are not changing myObj, can `getSomething` use either the old version or new version, and if so, then non-synchronized should be OK.

Comment: If it's OK to use an old value of `myObj`, you don't need a lock.  But you updated it for a reason, didn't you?

Comment: I agree with @cHao . However, if you could outline the relevant lines of getSomething(), then we could give a definite answer.

Comment: @cHao: That should be an answer.

Comment: Why is this question tagged `C++11`?  It seems to be purely a Java question.  (The answer would be very different in C++, since both the semantics of assignment and which operations are intrinsically atomic are very different.)

Answer (score 3):

You need to declare `myObject` volatile, otherwise `getSomething()` method may not see updated object. Other than that I cannot see any synchronization issues in the above code

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you must synchronize your access to the shared variable properly. According to the [Java Memory Model](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html), your code doesn't guarantee [happens-before](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5) relationship between the read and the write in all possible executions.

Proper synchronization doesn't always mean using locks; In your case, declaring myObj as volatile can do the job (assuming that you don't mutate it after construction).

Answer (score 1):

The write to a reference variable is indeed atomic.

But without the lock (or some other kind of synchronization) the other threads are not guaranteed to see the updated value of `myObj` to the extreme that they will see only its initial value (`null`, if you did not assign it in the constructor).

You will be hard-pressed to write a program in such a way that it exhibits exactly this extreme behavior, but without synchronization you will definitely get inconsistent results when a thread calls `updateObj` and than some other threads call `getSomething` and use the obsolete `myObj` instance.

The simplest way to ensure that `getSomething` uses the latest `myObj` is to declare the `myObj` as `volatile`.

Comment: The problem can be even worse than stale values. A reader thread may see partial data in myObj, as if it was partially constructed.

Answer (score 0):

yes you need some locking over here. because I can see is both different function is called by different threads and you are using `myObj` in `getSomething()` method.
   Now assume when your child thread is executing `getSomething()` and at the same time your main thread have change `myObj` then your program will be victim of the race condition and you may not get the desired output.
  but though it depends on the overall program you write. hope this helps

Comment: The child thread will be running `doSomething` in *either* the new `myObj`, or an old-as-of-the-time-it-finishes one.  It'll run to completion in whichever one it starts in, and the latter isn't necessarily the end of the world.  :)  It depends entirely on why `myObj` has changed.  (Not my downvote, BTW.)

Comment: @cHao but what is the old and new have been used and passed in some business logic in program will not it affect the program flow? let me correct if m wrong

Comment: @SanjayRajjadi how will this cause a race condition?

Answer (score 0):

- The `updateObj()` needs to be synchronized so that the shared mutable `myObj` is written to  atomically.

  - `MyObjects.getSomething()` needs to be a synchronized method if it uses shared mutable values.

Comment: Reference reads and writes are already atomic in Java. You don't need to do anything extra to get atomicity if that's the only concern. What's not atomic is read/modify/write...which doesn't seem to be the case here.